# Using the bisection method for multiple real root in a third degree polynomial +Sturm's Theorem

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, roots, bisection

I am exploring root-finding algorithms and methods for finding roots of third degree polynomials. For the bisection method, I understand that one must specify an interval which contains the roots if $f(a)f(b) = 0$. finding the root would be easily achieved with a cubic equation with one real root. However, in the case of two or more real roots, the method will converge towards only one, depending on location.

In order to combat this problem, I was thinking of a method that allows us to divide the polynomial into intervals such that each interval only contains one root. is there a way to do that, and are there alternatives such that I do not use other method than the bisection method?

Additionally, I read that Sturm's theorem can define an interval in which a root is located, but how effective is it for multiple roots, and does the condition of no square apply to the polynomial itself or its factors?

thanks in advance

Comment: You could use the real roots of the derivative (if any) to subdivide the interval, as between two real roots there will be a maximum or minimum. This fact is also known as Rolle theorem. // Do not use bisection in a production environment. There are easy fast alternatives, and not so easy even faster methods (that you want to use from a library).

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: Note that bisection won't work for a root or even order. You need a change of sign. That said, a polynomial of degree $3$ has at least one change of sign, so you can find one root $a$, and then divide the polynomial by $x-a$, to get a polynomial of degree two that you can sole directly.

Comment: Of course there are also exact methods for polynomials of degree $3$. You have to take care of numerical stability though (for degree $2$ as well). If it's a problem, note you don't need to use complex numbers to find real roots, there is a method using trigonometric or hyperbolic functions.